# Accessing class variable from another class

Tags: c#, oop

I have a class `A` that contains a `List` field.

```
public class A
{
    public List<int> list = new List<int>();
}
```

I would like to remove an element from the `list` from class `B` without making the list in class `A` `static`. How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you need to make it static? you set it to `public` so anyone with an instance of class `A` can already get to `list` and modify it.

Comment: create class A object in class B to access the list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could [create an instance of class](http://www.dotnetperls.com/new) `A` inside a method in class `B`. Then you could access the `list` field, like this:

```
public class B
{
    void method()
    {
        A a = new A();
        int item = 2;
        a.list.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind instantiating it, it's simply

```
A a = new A();
a.list...
```

If you don't want to instantiate a new one, you can pass an existing instance to B on its constructor:

```
public class B{

    private A myA;
    public B( A a) {
        this.myA = a;
    }
    public doSomething(){
        this.myA....
    }
}
```

Now you can use A as a field of B.

Comment: How can i pass it to B?

Answer (score 1):

A more OOP solution for this problem would be:

```
public class A
{
    private List<int> list = new List<int>();
    List<int> getList();
    void setList(List<int> list);
}
```

Then in the code where it is used,

```
A a = new A();
List<int> list = a.getList();
modify list as you want
a.setList(list);
```